# Make Selenium work in Ubuntu after update

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

So recently google updated their chrome version to 102.something.112 but chromedriver still on 102.something.61 and for that reason selenium is not able to run without crashing

```
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Stacktrace:

```
 chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") #bypass OS security model
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage") #overcome limited resource problems
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```

I already defined the path to chromedriver and also for chrome binary but that just don`t work, any ideas?

Comment: I can see a higher version of chromedriver than what you mentioned. did you already try it? https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=102.0.5005.61/

Comment: that is exactly the one I'm using, sadly is not compatible as other users already reported :l

Comment: Make sure you have the latest update for chrome. if it does not work even then, consider logging a defect here with all the details. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/list

Comment: doesn`t work, sadly